# html/css header and footer not filling the whole space

Tags: html, css

Hello I'm having a problem with my layout, when I'm resizing it, it's not filling the whole space. Please check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4mLu/)

My sample code:

```
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }

        p, a, h1 {
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        .container {
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }

        .content {
            width: 96%;
            max-width: 720px;
            min-width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 245px; /* Height of the footer element */
        }

        .headerWrapper {
            position: absolute;
            height: 85px;
            background: #19A347;
            z-index: 9000;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #header {
            width: 960px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
        }

        .logo {
            position: absolute;
        }

        .logoimg {
            display: block;
            width: 155px;
            height: 85px;
            text-indent: -9999px;   
        }

        .globalnav {
            float: right;
            clear: right;
            padding: 8px 8px 0 0;
            display: block;
        }
        .nav-menu {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .nav-menu li {
            display: inline;
        }
        .nav-menu a {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 15px;
            margin: 5px;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 20px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .nav-menu a:hover {
            color: #66C285; 
        }


        #footer {
            height: 245px;
            background: #1c1c1c;
            position: absolute;
            bottom:0;
            left:0;
            width: 100%;
        } 

        .cols-container {
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 960px;
            min-width: 900px;
            overflow: hidden;
        } 

        .cols-container div {
            width: 20%;
            float: left;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 15px;
        }

        .heading {
            font-size: 20px;
            color: #fff;
            background: #009933;
            padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
        }

        #footer li, a {
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        #footer a:hover {
            color: #999;
        };
```

I don't know what's making it act like this way. Help is truly appreciated.

Comment: Remove `width:100%` from `.headerWrapper `.

Comment: @Vucko if I remove width: 100% from .headerWrapper it's not filling the whole space if the window is in full screen

Comment: Why are you using `position:absolute` for that ?

Comment: @Vucko I just want the nav to be fixed

Comment: [Will this suit](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4mLu/3/)?

Comment: @Vucko thanks for this but the footer is not filling up the space and the header can't be moved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the `width` between `header` and `headerWrapper`:

```
.headerWrapper {
position: absolute;
height: 85px;
background: #19A347;
z-index: 9000;
width: 960px;

}

#header {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}
```

You also should change these rules:

```
.cols-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 900px;
    overflow: hidden;
} 

.content {
width: 96%;
max-width: 720px;
min-width: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 10px;
padding-bottom: 245px; /* Height of the footer element */
}
```

to the min-width you want:

```
 .cols-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
 } 

.content {
width: 96%;
max-width: 720px;
min-width: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 10px;
padding-bottom: 245px; /* Height of the footer element */
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4mLu/2/)

Comment: if I remove width: 100% from .headerWrapper it's not filling the whole space if the window is in full screen

Comment: Hi thanks, but why is it when I still resized it to smaller screens, it shows a little space?

Comment: Your `min-width` limits your minimum width. If you want smaller screen change the value to a smaller one.